# How to prevent eclipse from deploying test classes on Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, glassfish

I have a Maven project, containing the typical folders `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` and I am using Eclipse 3.7 with m2e 1.0.and Maven Integration for WTP 1.4.0 . Eclipse is used during development to deploy the application on an server (Tomcat or Glassfish), but it deploys the test classes from `src/test/java` folder too.

I do not want the test classes deployed, so how can I "exclude" that directory from eclipse-tomcat deployment?

Comment: Have you installed m2e plugin and m2e WTP in your Eclipse ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, I forgot this information: I am using m2e 1.0.100

Comment: I asked if you have installed m2e for WTP ? Can you post your pom?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, yes I have it: Maven Integration for WTP version 1.14.0

Comment: What does `Deployment Assembly` in the project `Properties` show?  It should not have `src/main/test`.

Comment: @Raghuram: Thanks I got the problem with your help

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is configurable in Eclipse how to handle and deploy the different folders, somehow the Eclipse plugin M2Eclipse should configure Eclipse right, it seams that the configuration sometimes is done and sometimes not.

So one has to check this two settings:

- Project Properties\Java Build Path(Tab)Source : Outputfolder for `<PROJECT>/src/test/java` as well as `<PROJECT>/src/test/resources` must be `<PROJECT>/target/test-classes`
- Project Properties\Deployment Assembly : There must be NO entry for `<PROJECT>/src/test/java` or `<PROJECT>/target/test-classes`[image]

Comment: For me it was sufficient to just exclude any `src/test` folders from `Deployment Assembly`.

Comment: This workaround works if you do not need to change maven profiles. I've got a project configured with maven profiles and whenever I change them, m2e reconfigures the deployment assembly and I need to go and edit it again.

Comment: How do I exclude folders? I can only "add" ...

Comment: @DavidDunham: are you talking about **subfolders** in one of the folders listed in that dialog?

Answer (score 7):

When this happens, perform "Maven -> Update Project..." from the project properties context menu.  In my experience, this correctly reconfigures Eclipse.