# Preventing Test Classes from being exported into jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-juno

I am trying to build a Runnable jar file using the Eclipse>Export>Runnable Jar File option.
Things are fine except that it is also exporting my test classes
I am only selecting classes from my src/java folder and not anything from src/test folder

One way out is to add the MANIFEST file later after building as a normal jar. But would like to know if there is a way to prevent tets classes from being exported

Answer (score 2):

In the `Java Build Path` `Source` menu add the main and test sources separately. Now in the `Deployment Assembly` menu remove the test sources.

Is that what you're looking for?

[have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818804/how-to-prevent-eclipse-from-deploying-test-classes-on-tomcat)

Comment: main and test are added separately in build path. What is deployment Assembly?

Comment: Right click on the project and there. I don't know your setup but for me it's the menu above build path. http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Eclipse-Web-Deployment-Assembly.jpg