# prevent m2e-wtp to deploy test classes

Tags: maven, m2e, m2e-wtp

my problem is, that test Classes get deployed when inside eclipse.
A normal maven build is correct. So i see  the culprit in M2e(-wtp)
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820317/2527174)  does not help me. My eclipse settings are set per default accordingly as the answer states.
But, after a Maven Update Project i can see an entry in the Java Build path. There is an entry. under the tab Source, for src/test/java with an output folder Target/test-classes. Additionally, this folder apears under the tab Order and Export as checked. 
When i manually delete src/test/java from the 'source folder' Tab Eclipse deploys correctly.
Is there any configuration in m2e(-wtp) which can prevent this behaviour?

Since the folder(test-classes) does NOT appear in our poms, i assume that it must have to do with the default behaviour of the plugins.
Environment

```
    Eclipse Kepler
    m2e-wtp  1.0.0.20130613-0136
    m2e 1.4.0

version.ear.plugin       2.6
version.ejb.plugin       2.3
version.resources.plugin 2.6
version.surefire.plugin  2.16
version.war.plugin       2.3
version.compiler.plugin   2.3.1
```